# Streaming a Remote server's MP3 using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, streaming, mp3

I have been trying this for so long, but was not able to implement this.

My problem is: 
    I have multiple servers, one is hosting my website http://server1/ and others are storing my mp3 files http://server2/.

Now, what I want is: people to listen to whatever I(admin) is playing. For that I have created one dedicated page for admin http://server2/admin.php, where admin can play any songs from the repository.

But I am stuck at streaming it out to the users. I want to populate a URL which will stream out the songs i am playing on admin side. Something like http://server1/stream.php

Please help me. Also suggest some player which can play streaming data for php/js.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.icecast.org/ or http://stream.xmoov.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Shoutcast Internet radio](http://www.shoutcast.com/broadcast-tools) for streaming the mp3. it can be configured with win-amp.